# На самом сайте отображаются php запросы

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой на своем сайте, на нём отображаются запросы на сервер, прикрепил скриншоты, в чём может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не _"пхп-запросы"_, а проблема может быть в отсутствие какого-то плагина

Comment: Это называется шорткоды. Их реализация осуществляется в плагинах или теме. У вас не установлен или не активирован плагин, либо вы сменили тему.

Comment: А еще у вас искорежены кавычки. Вместо `"` в шорткодах везде `»` Так шорткод работать не будет. Выключайте плагины по одному, пока не увидите `"` (или пока не начнет работать шорткод).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь никакого запроса нет. В контенте страницы записаны шорт-коды (short-code).

Тут два варианта, или плагин не активен (либо удален), или же в тексте страницы шорт-коды записаны не как положено, то есть [example], а в кодированом виде, То есть так:  & #091; example  & #093;